# Converting date to Monday of that week

Tags: r, datetime

I found this formula for converting dates to the Monday of that week:

```
x <- as.Date("2015-07-17")
y <- (x-c(6:0))[format((x-c(6:0)),"%w")=="1"]
```

How might I adapt the formula for use on a column of dates?

---

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2014-08-09", "2014-08-10", "2014-08-11", "2014-11-04"))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$week <- (df$date-c(6:0))[format((df$date-c(6:0)),"%w")=="1"]
```

Will throw:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt? The formula seems fine..

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes.

Comment: In the formula you converted string to date with `as.Date`. In the dataframe you still have as string. Could be that?

Comment: Is `dplyr` tag related here in some way?

Comment: If this is the only date arithmetic you needed you have a good solution now; otherwise look into `lubridate` (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/paper).  Has made my date processing much more pleasant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
prevM <-function(x)
        7 * floor(as.numeric(x-1+4) / 7) + as.Date(1-4,origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Then

```
 prevM(as.Date(c("2015-07-17","2015-07-16","1974-02-10")))
```

Will produce:

```
[1] "2015-07-13" "2015-07-13" "1974-02-04"
```

You can find it here:[Previous Monday date](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/288846.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2014-08-09", "2014-08-10", "2014-08-11", "2014-11-04"))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  df$date[i] <- (as.Date(df$date[i])-c(6:0))[format((as.Date(df$date[i])-c(6:0)),"%w")=="1"]
}
```